# What is it called when "I don't like X" is used to mean "I positively *dislike* X", or "We do not recommend Xing" is used for "We *discourage* Xing"?

Tags: negation, semantics, litotes

I’m wondering if there’s a term that linguists or rhetoricians use for this (semantic?) phenomenon.

In both cases, it seems as though ‘not’ no longer expresses the *mere absence or negation* of what it modifies, but instead expresses the *polar opposite* of what it modifies. It's as if someone could say “My car is not black” to mean “My car is white”, “It’s not a terrible movie” to mean “It’s an excellent movie”, or “I don’t love you” to mean “I hate you”.

I recognize that there is something similar to this that is a mere matter of ad hoc irony, understatement, or litotes, often accompanied with a special tone of voice or facial expression (“He’s not exactly a brain surgeon, is he?”, “That test was no picnic”). But what I’m asking about seems to be a fixed part of the language and can be found in extremely dry and mechanical writing: “Use of this product in XYZ way is not recommended”. (Is it just fossilized litotes?)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no such thing as mere negation. It's a very important constituent of language, logic, and communication. What you refer to goes under many names in the literature: _Negative-Raising_ is the difference between _I don't think he's here_ and _I don't claim he's here_ -- the first means the same with the negative downstairs - _I think he's not here_ - but the second doesn't. Another phenomenon is Gricean implicatures, like _He tried to open it_ implicating failure ("if that's all you can say"). Check out sources on [Negation](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler - When I said “mere absence or negation”, I didn’t intend to suggest that negation is unimportant. I merely intended to contrast it with “express[ing] the polar opposite”. When you say that there’s no such thing as mere negation, are you saying that this apparent contrast isn't a real contrast?

Comment: I'm saying that the circumstances you give as examples are somewhat confused and touch on a number of complications. If you're pointing to a single contrast, it's not clear which one you intend. _Not_ rarely expresses anything itself; it's always part of some construction, cued in by something in the context, like _I could care_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I always think it's odd that to many/most Americans, *I could care less* means the same as the logically straightforward British version *I **couldn't** care less*. As ever, BrE is tending to fall in line with the dominant culture, but I still struggle with that one.

Comment: @JohnLawler - After further research and some help from other commenters, I’ve concluded that the phenomenon I'm referring to is typically called “Neg-raising” (as in Laurence R. Horn's chapter in the _Oxford Handbook of Negation_ (Déprez & Espinal 2020)), and is called “subordinate negation implicature” by Huddleston and Pullum (in a discussion Horn refers to). I’m not sure what confused you about my examples. Both _like_ and _recommend_ are given as examples by Huddleston and Pullum, and the very similar _want_ and _suggest_ are given as examples by Horn.

Comment: The old-fashioned term for this sort of phenomenon is **litotes.**

Comment: I saw your title on the HNQ list and wondered why this Chinese person Xing is involved.

Comment: @rrutouowrpeie Good for you for doing the research. You'll note that _Negative-Raising_ was my first suggestion, though what you described included a lot of stuff that wasn't syntactic, so I couldn't be sure.

Comment: Did you not notice, ‘not’ does not appear in both cases?

Comment: Further, did you not notice how any or all of the given examples might actually matter… or not?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<sup>Adapted from another answer of mine</sup>

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* have a subchapter covering the more general phenomenon laid out in the body of the question. It is titled "Increased specificity of negation". The rest of this post deals with cases such as those set out in the title.

> 1. I don't seem to have enough time.
> 2. I seem to not have enough time.

**Short answer**:

Some verbs that take clauses as complements create *subordinate negation implicatures*. This means that in a [verb] + [clause] combination, if we negate the verb, we imply the same meaning as if we had negated the complement clause. So, for example, the sentence "I do **not want** you to go" implies  "I want you to **not go**". This means that we can, in most circumstances choose which part to negate when dealing with these types of verb. As a general rule of thumb, English speakers prefer to have the negation as early on in the sentence as possible. This makes the sentences far easier to process.

*NEG-raising* is a technical term which endeavours to explain how subordinate negation implicatures arise through a grammatical transformation.

---

**Full answer:**

It is a fact known to millions of hardworking English language students all over the world that native English speakers strongly prefer negating the verbs ***think***, ***believe*** and ***want***, amongst others, to negating the complement clauses that they license. So, for instance, all other things being equal, we prefer:

> (1).  *I don’t believe that the Yeti exists*.

to:

> (2).  *I believe that the Yeti doesn’t exist*.

We also would tend to prefer:

> - *I don’t think I’m going to find it*.

to:

> - *I think I’m not going to find it*.

and there is absolutely no doubt that:

> - *I don't want to go*.

is far more customary than the rather stilted:

> - *I want to not go*.

Notice that what is implied by (1) is the same as what is literally encoded in (2). However, (1) does not in fact strictly semantically encode the same information as (2) at all. If we made no further pragmatic assumptions about what the speaker of (1) intended to convey, then the maximum we should be entitled to decode is that the speaker does not possess a positive creedal attitude about the existence of Yetis. It is entirely possible that the speaker may have no definite opinion about the existence or non-existence of Yetis, in which case they would not be able to truthfully commit to either a belief or disbelief in them. This might be due to an agnostic state of mind, or it may be merely because the speaker has never even thought about it. To commit the speaker of (1) to a belief in (2) is potentially doing them a great disservice.

Be that as it may, most listeners would understand (1) as conveying the same as (2), and they are indeed entitled to, because most speakers - unless they were wishing to be very explicitly technical about it - would prefer the former to the latter to convey the very same information. What is interesting here is that speakers are modifying the verb denoting the action of belief in order to manipulate the listener’s understanding of the object of the belief - the information in the complement clause. More specifically they are negating the verb denoting the believing, but implying a negation of the complement clause.

This phenomenon is known as SUBORDINATE NEGATION IMPLICATION. Verbs that tend to generate such implicatures seem to be verbs that denote states of intention, epistemic stance or opinion, or those which can be used performatively for advice. Dynamic verbs which denote actions, changes of mental states and so forth do not tend to generate these implicatures.  Compare the following sentences with the dynamic verb ***say***:

> *He didn't say that she danced*.
>
> *He said that she didn't dance*.

Here the two sentences do not convey the same information at all. We are not likely to infer the information in the second sentence when we read the first.

One more factor comes into play here. Verbs that generate subordinate negation implicatures, tend to be what are described in the *CaGEL* (*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Huddleston and Pullum, 2002) as *medium strength* verbs. They contrast for example 'stronger' ***know*** with 'medium strength' ***believe***. The reason that these verbs tend to generate such implicatures is merely that, pragmatically, it does not seem very informative to tell somebody that you don't have a medium strength stance about something. We tacitly infer, on this basis, the more informative proposition that the speaker has a stance about a negative idea.

However, with so-called stronger verbs, on the other hand, it *is* informative to convey that your confidence in a stance is not 100%, or contrastingly with weak verbs to convey that that not even the slightest positive attitude is given to the proposition in the complement clause. The strong and weak usages of the following verbs do not, therefore, generate subordinate negation implicatures:

> *I don't know that she went*. ≠ *I know that she didn't go*.
>
> *I don't suspect her of stealing.* ≠ *I suspect her of not stealing*.

As to why speakers actually prefer to negate verbs such as ***want*** and ***believe*** rather than to negate their complement clauses, I do not believe that anybody knows (- by which I want you to infer that I believe that nobody knows).

Comment: I googled “subordinate negation implication”, but found no results outside of Stack Exchange. Do you know of any texts that use this terminology?

Comment: Yes: Huddleston and Pullum, 2002, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*. I've now edited the full title into the text.

Comment: I just checked my pdf copy of that text, and again “subordinate negation implication” is nowhere to be found. Are you thinking of a different text, or perhaps slightly different terminology?

Comment: 'Adapted from another answer of mine': could we have a link, please?

Comment: @rrutouowrpeie See pp.838-843 Especially under the subheading on p.840 "Matrix verbs and adjectives allowing the subordinate negation implicature." You might have more luck searching with 'implicature', where that corresponds to the inference that the listener makes as opposed to the process of generating it.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like Huddleston and Pullum call the phenomenon “subordinate negation implicature” rather than “subordinate negation implication”. It also looks like most linguists discuss it under the label “Neg-raising” (for example, Laurence R. Horn's chapter in the _Oxford Handbook of Negation_ (Déprez & Espinal 2020), which refers directly to Huddleston and Pullum’s discussion).

Comment: One of the reasons nobody except H&P and their diaconate use the term "subordinate negation implicature" is that a new term with new morphology and unknown epicyclic claims is not what most linguists think they need for a well-known syntactic phenomenon with its own perfectly referential name, which we are able to recognize either in its full form _Negative-Raising_, or its contracted one _Neg-Raising_. It's subordinate like any phenomenon governed by a verb is subordinate, and it's certainly involved with negation, though calling it an "implicature" is misleading.

Comment: @JohnLawler How is it misleading calling it an implicature?

Comment: It's an implicature like the fact that sense verbs can take 4 different types of complement is an implicature -- i.e, it's something you're sposta know about the verb. Everything's an implicature of some sort or another; it doesn't add any information to use the term; in this case, it avoids the syntactic implications of having two synonymous sentences connected by a syntactic rule governed by the predicate, like Dative or _Tough_-Movement. I don't like H&P's syntactic theory because it's all name magic, but you gotta use CGEL brand names

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, entailments aren't implicatures and vice versa. CGEL'S difference here is not one of terminology, but analysis - in the sense that they sidestep the issue of whether there is a syntactic rule there, or it's all semantics and pragmatics, or a bit of all three. Whether decisive or not, there are good arguments for the latter two. For example, if the syntactic rule exists, one would indeed expect  the matrix negation sentence to entail the subordinate one, but it doesn't appear to (see discussion in post above). {1/2}

Comment: It's a minor governed rule, like the ones I mentioned - _Tough_-Movement and Dative - and "one" (i.e, I) would not expect that outcome from the non-existence of a syntactic rule. Yes, there's pragmatics, but making everything an ill-defined term like "implicature" is not different from making them all "rules" or some other term. What's needed is vector syntax.

Comment: @JohnLawler and so the sentences are arguably not synonymous. If there was a rule or transformation involved we would not expect factors like tense or pragmatics to have a strong influence on whether the matrix negation implied a subordinate one, but they do. For example, if you put OP's "We don't recommend Xing" into the past tense still keeping the stative meaning, it no longer seems to strongly imply "We recommended not Xing" or "We used to recommend not Xing".

Comment: @JohnLawler The implicature is not the rule or the process, it is just the proposition that is being implied. Whether there is a syntactic rule or not, there is an entailment or presupposition or implicature there, but none of those are rules. [Comment above this one cross posted!]

Comment: No, none of those are syntactic rules. Syntactic rules are brainless and don't care what is meant or implied. They are the mechanical physiology of meaning. They are found in situations where they're useful, like Dative with 3-place transfer verbs, and Neg-Raising with mental imagination verbs, so they're not dissociated from the semantics. As Haj Ross is wont so say, verbs of a feather flock together.

Comment: Certainly anybody looking at the verb lists in Levin will notice the semantic and pragmatic cohesion of the predicates for each rule. But you can't invent'em -- the presence of _do_ is not the same as _Do_-support, for instance. If you prefer, I usually refer to the logical phenomena by saying that Neg-raising predicates are transparent to negation. If you wanna call it an implicature, fine, but I don't think it needs a special name (and no doubt a special implicature type of its own to go with its grand new name :-). I suspect if one looked properly, one would find other transparencies.

Comment: The addition of adverbs to such constructs can often avoid the "neg-raising" tendencies of the verbs.  Saying "I don't *particularly* want to go" means my desire to go is not stronger than my desire to do other things, but doesn't imply active opposition to the idea of going.

Comment: @supercat Great example.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to deal with a complicated range of phenomena.  To generalise your question, you seem to be interested that sometimes "A is not f" means simply that the proposition "A is not f" false and no more than that, while, at other times "A is not f" means "A is g" (where g is the polar opposite of f, rather than merely its contradictory).  *Contradictory* is a logical term from what you explain.

You are right about there being a distinction of this kind.  To some extent, the distinction depends on context. An example of this is, in fact, the sentence "A is not good".  If we are dealing with, say, the evaluation of schools or books, where they are rated 'excellent', 'good', 'satisfactory', 'unsatisfactory', and I say "Super Duper Academy is not good", nothing follows, except possibly it is unlikely to be excellent either.  If it had been, you might think it a bit perverse of me to leave it at "SDA is not good".  But in a more general context "A is not good" does indeed imply that A is worse than just OK, **if you are British**.  Similarly, you can serve a British guest the best dinner ever, and must not feel offended if you are rewarded with an enthusiastic "I say, that was not bad!"  It is, as you say, a kind of understatement. So as a member of the British Civil Service, I was quite clear that if my boss said "It would be helpful if you can have that analysis to me for Friday", that meant "have it to me by Friday or else!".

It is not clear, more broadly, that there is a good word for the 'not good' phenomenon.  Rather this is a characteristic of words with well established, automatic antonyms:  *good/bad*, *wise/foolish*, fair/unfair and so forth.  The denial of one pole sends a listener mentally straight to the polar opposite.

Comment: "Not good" is not a Britishism, in AmE (conversational) "x is not good" broadly means "x is definitely bad". There are exceptions where you might say something like "x is not good, it is _great_" but that is usually humorous and it's only funny because of the contrast with the normal (bad) meaning.

Comment: @user3067860  That is probably right.  However, I would still claim that the British are in general more given to understatement than Americans are.